# Ovirt doesn't create live snapshot

Tags: centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, rhev

I installed oVirt. If I suspent VM and create snapshot it's ok, but if I try to do live snapshot on the stage "Finalizing" ovirt have fail.
Ovirt, VDSM and NFS storages are on the same local server.

logs:

```
#cat /var/log/messages
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.LVM WARNING lvm vgs failed: 5 [] ['  Volume group "08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4" not found']
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.StorageDomain WARNING Resource namespace 08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4_imageNS already registered
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.StorageDomain WARNING Resource namespace 08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4_volumeNS already registered
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.LVM WARNING lvm vgs failed: 5 [] ['  Volume group "2f34862e-2602-4d6e-b418-72881113d3f6" not found']
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.StorageDomain WARNING Resource namespace 2f34862e-2602-4d6e-b418-72881113d3f6_imageNS already registered
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.StorageDomain WARNING Resource namespace 2f34862e-2602-4d6e-b418-72881113d3f6_volumeNS already registered
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.LVM WARNING lvm vgs failed: 5 [] ['  Volume group "947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d" not found']
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.StorageDomain WARNING Resource namespace 947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d_imageNS already registered
May 18 15:45:42 KVMServer vdsm Storage.StorageDomain WARNING Resource namespace 947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d_volumeNS already registered
May 18 15:45:51 KVMServer vdsm vm.Vm ERROR vmId=`05b988a8-ead9-40dd-bec1-29af3ef2a503`::Unable to take snapshot#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/share/vdsm/libvirtvm.py", line 2117, in snapshot#012    self._dom.snapshotCreateXML(snapxml, snapFlags)#012  File "/usr/share/vdsm/libvirtvm.py", line 541, in f#012    ret = attr(*args, **kwargs)#012  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/vdsm/libvirtconnection.py", line 111, in wrapper#012    ret = f(*args, **kwargs)#012  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1623, in snapshotCreateXML#012    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainSnapshotCreateXML() failed', dom=self)#012libvirtError: unsupported configuration: reuse is not supported with this QEMU binary
```

Vdsm log:

```
#cat /var/log/vdsm/vdsm.log
    15:46:44,246::resourceManager::227::ResourceManager.Request::(grant) ResName=`Storage.12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f`ReqID=`83c92dd4-ac96-48f5-a94f-34d64d19f418`::Granted request
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,246::task::794::TaskManager.Task::(resourceAcquired) Task=`d0366f9a-e0f5-4e11-9cba-2ad4a99bcc5c`::_resourcesAcquired: Storage.12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f (shared)
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,246::task::957::TaskManager.Task::(_decref) Task=`d0366f9a-e0f5-4e11-9cba-2ad4a99bcc5c`::ref 1 aborting False
    Thread-28672::INFO::2013-05-18 15:46:44,249::logUtils::44::dispatcher::(wrapper) Run and protect: getStoragePoolInfo, Return response: {'info': {'spm_id': 1, 'master_uuid': '947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d', 'name': 'Default', 'version': '3', 'domains': '2f34862e-2602-4d6e-b418-72881113d3f6:Active,947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d:Active,08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4:Active', 'pool_status': 'connected', 'isoprefix': '/rhev/data-center/12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f/08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4/images/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', 'type': 'NFS', 'master_ver': 1, 'lver': 1}, 'dominfo': {'2f34862e-2602-4d6e-b418-72881113d3f6': {'status': 'Active', 'diskfree': '329499279360', 'alerts': [], 'disktotal': '412849537024'}, '947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d': {'status': 'Active', 'diskfree': '329499279360', 'alerts': [], 'disktotal': '412849537024'}, '08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4': {'status': 'Active', 'diskfree': '329499279360', 'alerts': [], 'disktotal': '412849537024'}}}
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,249::task::1151::TaskManager.Task::(prepare) Task=`d0366f9a-e0f5-4e11-9cba-2ad4a99bcc5c`::finished: {'info': {'spm_id': 1, 'master_uuid': '947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d', 'name': 'Default', 'version': '3', 'domains': '2f34862e-2602-4d6e-b418-72881113d3f6:Active,947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d:Active,08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4:Active', 'pool_status': 'connected', 'isoprefix': '/rhev/data-center/12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f/08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4/images/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', 'type': 'NFS', 'master_ver': 1, 'lver': 1}, 'dominfo': {'2f34862e-2602-4d6e-b418-72881113d3f6': {'status': 'Active', 'diskfree': '329499279360', 'alerts': [], 'disktotal': '412849537024'}, '947c28b6-3a4d-4bbb-9d75-40ba4442d39d': {'status': 'Active', 'diskfree': '329499279360', 'alerts': [], 'disktotal': '412849537024'}, '08053dcb-8529-4a35-a41a-feedac107ff4': {'status': 'Active', 'diskfree': '329499279360', 'alerts': [], 'disktotal': '412849537024'}}}
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,250::task::568::TaskManager.Task::(_updateState) Task=`d0366f9a-e0f5-4e11-9cba-2ad4a99bcc5c`::moving from state preparing -> state finished
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,250::resourceManager::830::ResourceManager.Owner::(releaseAll) Owner.releaseAll requests {} resources {'Storage.12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f': < ResourceRef 'Storage.12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f', isValid: 'True' obj: 'None'>}
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,250::resourceManager::864::ResourceManager.Owner::(cancelAll) Owner.cancelAll requests {}
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,250::resourceManager::557::ResourceManager::(releaseResource) Trying to release resource 'Storage.12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f'
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,250::resourceManager::573::ResourceManager::(releaseResource) Released resource 'Storage.12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f' (0 active users)
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,250::resourceManager::578::ResourceManager::(releaseResource) Resource 'Storage.12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f' is free, finding out if anyone is waiting for it.
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,250::resourceManager::585::ResourceManager::(releaseResource) No one is waiting for resource 'Storage.12a193a4-bf02-11e2-8249-08606ef06a7f', Clearing records.
    Thread-28672::DEBUG::2013-05-18 15:46:44,251::task::957::TaskManager.Task::(_decref) Task=`d0366f9a-e0f5-4e11-9cba-2ad4a99bcc5c`::ref 0 aborting False
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your answer: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.ovirt.user/2527

you have an old qemu version that doesn't support live snapshots, you need a newer build (1.1 or higher)

PS: it would generally help if you post the actual versions of the packages you use, in the future

Answer (score -1):

This is normal behavior. You must pause vm then do snapshot.

Source: [pdf presentation about snapshot on rhev](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/slides/2011/linuxcon-japan/lcj2011_sorensen.pdf)

Comment: wrong. this presentation is 2 years old, and live snapshots were introduced into RHEV since. oVirt is always newer than RHEV, so live snapshots are definitely supported.